# Panning event for mxgraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am new to mxgraph and want to create a drag and drop for the entire graph. The behaviour I am looking for is described below:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use setPanning parameter of your graph:

```
graph.setPanning(true);
```

Where `graph` is reference to your mxGraph instance. [Here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.setPanning) is a documentation.

I need to mention that it's not "drag and drop", but "panning".